# Add / remove a port number to/from a URL with REGEX in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, replace

I've searched but was unable to find an existing regex function. Has anybody done this before?

I wish to add a port number, or remove a potantially existing one from a url in php. To use in some functions which translate a given url to the secure one, unsecure one, etc.

Now I need a second SSL secured site on the server so I need to dynamically add a port number while converting http to https, and remove any port number while converting from https to http.

Thanks,
Duck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a regex, you can use the built-in [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to break apart and reassemble the URL to match your requirements.

Comment: Thanks charles, it was the first thing I considered.

parse_url had some problems in the past, so I wanted to use regex, this could also work faster. After reading your reply I checked it again, looks like parse_url is fixed. I think I can use this.

Thanks,
Duck